# Expression<Func<TModel,TValue>> how can i get TValue's name?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

```
//ModelFor(person =>person.Name);
public void ModelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    //Result should be "Name"
    string nameOfTValue = ????;     
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify, do you want the name of the type TValue, or do you want the name of the parameter in the expression?

Comment: @casperOne `TValue` is always the return type and not a normal parameter.

Comment: You can get the PropertyInfo like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression/672212#672212 and then use `.Name` on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**: After your edit, I think you are want the name of the member involved in the expression, assuming of course that the expression is a member-expression in the first place.

```
((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name
```

To be more robust, you can do:

```
var memberEx = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

if (memberEx == null)
     throw new ArgumentException("Body not a member-expression.");

string name = memberEx.Member.Name;
```

---

**(Not relevant anymore):**

To get a `System.Type` that represents the type of the `TValue` type-argument, you can use the [**`typeof`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs(v=vs.71).aspx) operator.

You probably want:

```
typeof(TValue).Name
```

But also consider the `FullName` and `AssemblyQualifiedName` properties if appropriate.

This really has nothing to do with expression-trees; you can use this technique to get the type of a type-argument for *any* generic method.

Comment: Wow we wrote completely identical answers

Comment: I don't think this is right, I think that he wants the name of the parameter in the expression of type TValue.

Comment: @casperOne: You might be right; I'm not sure. Let's wait for clarification.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain? Perhaps you would like to take a look at the edit timestamps.

Answer (score 9):

> @Ani: I don't think this is right, I think that he wants the name of the parameter in the expression of type TValue

If this is true... this works 1 level deep only but might be handy anyway:

```
var nameOfTValue = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
```

Here is smarter implementation that should be able to deal with multiple levels:

```
 public class PropertyName{
    public static string For<T>(
      Expression<Func<T,object>> expression){
      var body=expression.Body;
      return GetMemberName(body);
    }
    public static string For(
      Expression<Func<object>> expression){
      var body=expression.Body;
      return GetMemberName(body);
    }
    public static string GetMemberName(
      Expression expression){
      if(expression is MemberExpression){
        var memberExpression=(MemberExpression)expression;
        if(memberExpression.Expression.NodeType==
           ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
          return GetMemberName(memberExpression.Expression)
            +"."+memberExpression.Member.Name;
        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
      }
      if(expression is UnaryExpression){
        var unaryExpression=(UnaryExpression)expression;
        if(unaryExpression.NodeType!=ExpressionType.Convert)
          throw new Exception(string.Format
            ("Cannot interpret member from {0}",expression));
        return GetMemberName(unaryExpression.Operand);
      }
      throw new Exception
        (string.Format("Could not determine member from {0}",expression));
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
var fieldName=PropertyName.For<Customer>(x=>x.Address.Region);
//fieldName==Address.Region
```

---

Another trick, this can be combined with reflection nicely:

```
public static T Set<T,TProp>(this T o,
   Expression<Func<T,TProp>> field,TProp value){
  var fn=((MemberExpression)field.Body).Member.Name;
  o.GetType().GetProperty(fn).SetValue(o,value,null);
  return o;
}
```

Allows to directly set properties with ease, can be useful for test fixtures:

```
var customer=new Customer("firstName","lastName");
customer.Set(x=>x.Name, "different firstName");
```